# Cannot connect Magento 2.x with zapier

Tags: zapier, magento2.2

I tried to connect my magento 2.2 site with zapier, but it shows error. Do I need to change any settings in admin to connect with zapier? Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: If you've read through [this help page](https://zapier.com/apps/magento/help) and none of those solutions are working, I'd write into support: https://zapier.com/contact-us

Comment: @xavdid, this help page is for magento 1.x connection with zapier.. my issue is with magento 2.2 site.. could you please give me another solution?

Comment: Have you written into Zapier support?

Comment: actually it looks like Zapier supports Magento v2 separately: https://zapier.com/apps/magento-v2/integrations

Comment: Ok, let me try for Zapier support.. Thanks.